# Rendering element to DOM based on dynamic sibling positions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a series of `<StrategyComponent>` elements that are rendered through a button click and are fully  draggable on the page. Currently the intial positions are static and all components will be rendered to the same position through the `initialPos` prop. However, since the user is free to move these wherever they want, I want to render each new component that the user adds a certain distance to the right of the right most `<StrategyComponent>` at the time (wherever that may be). How can I access this component or what is the best way to keep track of the right most bound in which to place incoming components.

Any help with this would be great. I'm sure it can be done, but I'm just getting used to React. Thanks!

`StrategyComponent.js`

```
class StrategyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        // creates a reference to wrapper div
        this.wrapper = React.createRef();
    }

    state = {
        pos: this.props.initialPos,
        dragging: false,
        rel: null, // position relative to the cursor
    };

    componentDidUpdate = (props, state) => {
        if (this.state.dragging && !state.dragging) {
            document.addEventListener("mousemove", this.onMouseMove);
            document.addEventListener("mouseup", this.onMouseUp);
        } else if (!this.state.dragging && state.dragging) {
            document.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.onMouseMove);
            document.removeEventListener("mouseup", this.onMouseUp);
        }
    };
    

    // calculate relative position to the mouse and set dragging=true
    onMouseDown = (e) => {
        // only left mouse button
        if (e.button !== 0) return;
        var pos = this.wrapper.current.getBoundingClientRect();

        this.setState({
            dragging: true,
            rel: {
                x: e.pageX - pos.x,
                y: e.pageY - pos.y,
            },
        });

        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    };

    onMouseUp = (e) => {
        this.setState({ dragging: false });
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    };

    onMouseMove = (e) => {
        if (!this.state.dragging) return;
        this.setState({
            pos: {
                x: e.pageX - this.state.rel.x,
                y: e.pageY - this.state.rel.y,
            },
        });
        this.props.handleParentResize(this.wrapper.current.getBoundingClientRect());
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    };

    render() {
        
        return (
            <div
                ref={this.wrapper}
                onMouseDown={this.onMouseDown}
                draggable
                className="component-wrapper"
                style={{ left: this.state.pos.x + "px", top: this.state.pos.y + "px" }}
            >
                <h3> Strategy Component {this.props.name}</h3>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

`App.js`

```
    class App extends Component {
       state = {
          numComponents: 1,
       };

       addStrategyComponent = () => {
          this.setState({ numComponents: this.state.numComponents + 1 });
       };


       render() {
          const components = [];

          for (var i = 0; i < this.state.numComponents; i++) {
              components.push(
                 <StrategyComponent key={i.toString()} name={i.toString()} initialPos={{ x: 200, y: 200 }} />
              );
           }

           return (
              <div className="App">
                 <button onClick={this.addStrategyComponent}>+</button>
                 <div className="components-wrapper">{components}</div>
              </div>
           );
        }
    }
```

Comment: you might want to use a [library](https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd) for this.